# zend framework bootstrap error

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

so I was adding this line to bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initSetDefaultKeywords() {
     $view = $this->bootstrap('view')->getResource('view');        
     $view->keywords = 'default keywords';
}
```

but then it would display the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "view" not found
```

so I tried adding `resources.view[] = ""` to application.ini, but then when that happens, all my view helpers suddenly stop working

```
* s

An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

    Message: Plugin by name 'X' was not found in the registry
```

how do i resolve this

current app.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "view"
resources.view[] = ""

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: could you post your current application.ini file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your application.ini:

```
resources.view[] = ""
resources.view.helperPath.MyNamespace_View_Helper = "MyNamespace/View/Helper"
```

Make sure to change `MyNamespace_View_Helper` to the actual prefix of your ViewHelpers.

You may also need to add the path to your AutoloaderNamespaces variable:

```
autoloaderNamespaces.MyNamespace = "MyNamespace_"
```

Comment: You don't need the first configuration line, the second sets up the config array for the view resource.

Comment: @Phil - Thanks, I was moreso trying to give @kamikaze_pilot reference of where the line should go.